# DataPrep - find first date

Tags: date, google-cloud-dataprep

Using DataPrep, I am trying to identify 2 dates based on the Order_Date, (1) the first order date and (2) the latest order date. I have used the min and max functions to find the first and last order dates however, the result is an integer. When I try to convert to date (assuming this integer is number of seconds after 1/1/1900) the resulting date is incorrect.

Would there be a better method to calculate this instead?

[Resulting columns created based on min and max functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5EW2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused by this question but it looks like the order date is being converted into Unix seconds (time since 01/01/1970.) Is the problem that you wanted a formatted date instead of the seconds? The fix here is to change the formatting of the computed columns to use a date format.